# How to use overflow with conditional statement in flutter

Tags: flutter, conditional-statements, flutter-layout

I get a lengthy result (location address) in my text box leading it to an error `RIGHT OVERFLOW BY 226 PIXEL`. I tried using `overflow` but the result is still the same.

```
Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
        Text(Provider
            .of<AppData>(context)
            .pickUpLocation != null
            ? Provider
            .of<AppData>(context)
            .pickUpLocation
            .placeName
                : "Add Home",overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis),
        SizedBox(
            height: 4.0,
        ),
        Text("Your home Address",
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black54, fontSize: 12.0)),
        ],
    )
```

Next, I tried using `Flexible` but the text is cut into half

Comment: Try wrapping `Text()` with `Container()` of specific width

Comment: The length of text isn't specific.

Comment: Wrap `Text ()` with `Expanded ()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap `Text` widget into `FittedBox` with `fit: BoxFit.scaleDown`